# Firefox special characters line height

Tags: html, firefox, special-characters

Has anyone else got the following:

Firefox (but not Chrome, IE or Safari) is for some reason displaying certain special characters such as dArr with a huge line height. When you select the character, the selection spans about 6 lines. It's ruining my HTML buttons and making them really big! (It's not a padding issue...)

Any ideas why this should be? Is it a new bug in FF? It wasn't happening last week...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show an example (http://jsfiddle.net) ?

Comment: can't reproduce this. i've just written "_this is a &dArr;​_" to a html file and compared the output of the latest versions of chrome and firefox. no difference.

Comment: For an example, just Google "dArr HTML". The result from faqs.org has a down arrow character in its description. If you select that character, what is the selection line height like? Is it bigger than selecting other, normal characters? For me it is much bigger...

Comment: Works as expected in my Firefox; any difference if you Help->restart with addons disabled

Comment: Tried restarting with addons disabled... didn't make a difference.
Oh well... I guess it's just a quirky thing with my computer...
Thanks everyone for your suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

The probable explanation is that the browser picks up the double arrow (or other special character) from a font that has a very large default line height, such as Cambria Math. The reason why different people have made different observations is that when the fonts being normally used do not contain a particular character, browsers will use some fallback, and then the results may depend on browser version and settings.

There are two fixes, and they can even be applied simultaneously:

1) Set the line height in CSS, e.g. `* { line-height: 1.3 }`. This overrides the default line height.

2) Set `font-family` on the text so that all characters used are present in the fonts listed and are acceptable in style. For example, if you include Arial Unicode MS and Lucida Sans Unicode, then Cambria Math won’t be used. But if you decide that Cambria Math is OK for the character, include it in the list but remember to use fix 1.

Comment: Thanks, but neither of  those worked.
The weirdest thing is that it just randomly started happening - the exact same pages were displaying fine before.
It's not a problem with my script, it seems to be a problem with my browser...

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce this symptom. What I do is to use Unicode characters from "block elements and geometric shapes" instead of "arrows" sub-range. In addition I'm avoiding "unusual" font families.

Sample view: ↓ ... ▼ (9960 or U25BC)